# Button should work as check box

Tags: android

Hi guys,

I am new to Android. I am having a button and layout, and I want to write a program such that when the button is selected the layout should be visible - otherwise, the layout should be invisible.

Comment: By 'the layout should be gone', what do you want to be shown on the screen? Nothing?

Comment: @ Jong not the parent layout , one of the child layout..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use toggle button

```
togglebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            if (togglebutton.isChecked()) {    // button on layout visible                  
                alarm_LL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {                // button off layout invisible   
                alarm_LL.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });                 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna use normal button, see below

```
    //create ImageView
    final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
    imgView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star);

    //create button and set action
    Button checkBtn = new Button(this);
    checkBtn.setText("Check Button");
    checkBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        private boolean ischecked = false;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ischecked = !ischecked;
            imgView.setVisibility(ischecked?View.VISIBLE:View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    this.addContentView(imgView, null);
    this.addContentView(checkBtn, null);
```